# SSI (Server Side includes) don't working on IIS 10 (Windows 11)

Tags: iis-10, windows-11, server-side-includes

1. IIS configured with Server Side includes
2. Additionally processing SSI adding to config
3. IIS handler mapping configured.
4. SSI file present and I can see it in browser.

But SSI still don't working. And I see in browser

```
  <!--#include virtual="/Header.htm" -->
```

[SSI configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/figoT.png)

What next? What I need more?

Comment: In what kind of page did you add `<!--#include xxxx -->`?

Comment: Not Include working only on ASP page, but not working on HTML page.

Comment: Duplicate to https://serverfault.com/questions/244352/why-wont-ssi-work-in-iis

Comment: @LexLi, NO, this is NOT duplicate. I made mapped handler. Moreover I made mapping even by two way - on IIS admin panel PLUS additionally in config, See carefully screen I added to question. On the left side you can see handler mapped on IIS panel, on the right side additionally mapping with config. But SSI still don't working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally SSI started working in my environment after two command

```
 C:\Windows\System32>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:asp -scriptErrorSentToBrowser:true
 Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/asp" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"

 C:\Windows\System32>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:asp -enableParentPaths:true
 Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/asp" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
```